# Strange static / low frequency noise with a Rode AI-1 on MME / ASIO drivers

Tags: microphone, adobe-audition, rode, hiss, spectrogram

I'm using a Rode NT1 microphone and a Rode AI-1, plugged into a USB-C port of a Windows 11 laptop (I have tried other ports too). I am using Adobe Audition.

When I try recording using MME drivers, a get a steady static hiss all the way through a recording. When I record using ASIO drivers, there is no audible static but there is noise (that I cannot hear) between 0 and 200 Hz (about -50 dB on the vertical scale).

Oddly, when I use the MME drivers for some sections it doesn't pick up any audio at all. For the two recordings, I said 'one, two, three, four' at the end, but the MME drivers only picked up 'two, three, four'.

You can see this here (ASIO on the left, MME on the right):

[image: ASIO drivers on the left, MME on the right]

And a close-up of the <200 Hz range:

[image: A close up of <200 Hz]

And here is the frequency analysis of an 'empty' part the ASIO one:

[image: Frequency analysis]

My two questions are:

1. Is this normal?
2. If not, what is the best way to troubleshoot / fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You should try to get better frequency resolution under 100 Hz, you could probably pinpoint the frequency then to better determine the source. For the MME driver, it could be some type of conversion error noise or even "enhancements" applied in Window's audio settings.

Comment: Thank you n00dles! Really good point about the Windows drivers. According to the frequency analysis curve, the frequency seems to be starting at 0Hz (!) and tails off at 190Hz - there's no single peak. I am a complete beginner though, so possibly I have misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to get better frequency resolution, I'm guessing it's going to be 50 or 60 Hz tone. FFT is analogous to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle; changing window type and size values can give you a pretty accurate frequency display or a pretty accurate temporal display. You have to sacrifice the accuracy of one for the other. But as temporal values aren't important here, you can go all out on frequency resolution with a larger FFT window size.